# Can anybody explain "The Loop" of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im forced to work with wordpress, and if you work with it, you probably know what i mean:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Its working, no question. But i do not understand what this actually means. Its not a ternary operator nor anything else i know. Ive never seen a statement like this in any php-projects ive worked on. So i got several questions:

1. What is this line exactly doing? I know that it gets all posts, iterates over them and ... what is this `the_post()` doing? And what are these doubledots doing?
2. Is this Wordpress-Only or could it be used somwhere else too?
3. Where is the current post stored?

Ive already googled it, but there are no information regarding my problem, noone seems to be interested in how wordpress works. I am, but i do not get it. If somebody got an explanation for me, it would be great.

Comment: In addition to the answer already given for alternative syntax for control structure you can check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117219/why-should-i-put-ifhave-posts-is-whilehave-posts-not-enough how it works for WP

Comment: The "double dots", you mean a colon, are ternary operators, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Ah colon ... didnt know how they were called. At least you know what i meant. But how can these be ternary operators, i thought you always need the structure `expression ? if_true_statement : if_false_statement`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); get_header(); ?>

The loop starts here:

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

and ends here:

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

This is using PHP's alternative syntax for control structures, and could also be expressed as:

<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here
            //
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Comment: Okay, this explains how this is written in "normal" php. But there are still 2 questions, could you answer these too if you know them?

Answer (score 3):

**the post()**

This function does not accept any parameters.

Return Values
This function does not return any values.

```
    <?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<h2>';
    the_title();
    echo '</h2>';
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

**have_posts()**
Parameters
This function does not accept any parameters.

Return Values
(boolean) 
True on success, false on failure.
Examples
The following example can be used to determine if any posts exist, and if they do, loop through them.

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // Your loop code
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>
```

Note
Calling this function within the loop will cause an infinite loop. For example, see the following code:

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
        // Display post
        if ( have_posts() ): // If this is the last post, the loop will start over
                // Do something if this isn't the last post
        endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

If you want to check if there are more posts in the current loop without this unfortunate side effect, you can use this function.

```
function more_posts() {
  global $wp_query;
  return $wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. What is LOOP**

The Loop is PHP code used by WordPress to display posts. Using The Loop, WordPress processes each post to be displayed on the current page, and formats it according to how it matches specified criteria within The Loop tags.

*It will fetch data related to specific page*

***:(colon) is used to tell condition/loop starts from here.*** *You can replace it with {   }(bracket quotes)*

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here
            //
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

**2. Is this Wordpress-Only or could it be used somwhere else too?**

yes of course you can use it.
You can access full wordpress functionality by including one core file with name of **"wp-blog-header.php"** that is located on root of wordpress directory.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Include this file in the top of your external file, you can access **wordpress database, wordpress function , wordpress hooks** too.

**3. Where is the current post stored?**

11 default tables are existed in wordpress database. You can see **wp_posts** table in database. all posts are store in this table.

suppose, if your are creating meta tag in your post, it will store in **wp_postmeta**

Answer (score 1):

It's just an alternative syntax for:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {          //open if
  while ( have_posts() ) {     //start while loop
    the_post();                //call a function
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

It's not wordpress specific and can be used in any php code.

Comment: So the colons are some kind of "replacement" for the curly brackets if you write the whole code inside the `<?php ?>` tags?

Comment: It's just an alternative syntax. you can also close php tags between both variants. But i'd also prefer it over curly braces with closing tags :)

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern.

**What is WordPress Loop?**

When we save data inside WordPress(posts, pages, almost everything) data gets saved as a row inside our database fx. MySQL.

WordPress dynamically query the database and finds which row corresponds to the page you are on, and pulls that data then displays it in that section.

As this is a dynamic query and executed in a repeated manner, it is called a **WordPress Loop**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

**What are these doubledots doing?** condition/loop starts from here `:(colon)` and is a ternary operators.

I think rest of the questions has been answered by others.